# FlashDevelop supporting 3 different languages (Eng, Kor, Chn)?

Tags: actionscript-3, air, ide, locale, flashdevelop

I developed an app (originally in Korean and English), but I want to add Chinese support.

When I move the Chinese translations from Word to FlashDevelop, though, some characters show up as boxes. When I run the app, they don't show up at all.

Does anyone have experience developing in multiple languages using the same IDE, or preferably, FlashDevelop?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the file encoding and check if the font you are using support this kind of character. If you use transformation like rotation and alpha, you need to embed your font. For french, I need to convert my file to UFT-8 and embed the font with accentued character.